# Cassandra db replacement

Tags: database

I am in desperate need of changing my cassandra db but i don't really know any good substitute for it. Basically my DB should be:

- multiple servers that can replicate ( mirror ) each other data
- capable of handling +/- 2-3K requests per second ( on 2 nodes, possibly capable of balancing itself between nodes)
- write/read as fast as possible ( write have bigger priority )
- capable of range/sort and if possible join ( Cassandra is retarded in these )

please, advice!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider Aerospike. (www.aerospike.com) Aerospike has built in replication and load balancing that provides high availability and high reliability, with very low latencies on primary key reads and writes (1-5ms) across the whole key space. Aerospike also has some pretty cool secondary index queries and aggregations.

Comment: Thank you, that seams to be epic choice for us. I will check it out!